# How to follow a string of different href in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to build a crawler in scrapy. I'm trying to extract data from webpage where people sell apartments. When I look for used apartments I get this url: 
http://www.metrocuadrado.com/apartamento/venta/usado/

and I get a list of all used apartments. I extracted a list of all href for each apartment but each href has this form

http://www.metrocuadrado.com/inmueble/venta-apartamento-sabaneta-3-habitaciones-3-banos-1-garajes/4211-852

so I can't use response.follow. How can I follow each href and extract info from it? Thank you!!

Comment: Why can't you use `response.follow` method? I don't see a reason why not. It's just a wrapper around `Request` constructor together with `response.urljoin`.

Comment: As @TomášLinhart mentioned response.follow should work. What is the issue you are facing? have you even tried using it in your code?

Comment: I get the following error:  'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'follow'

Comment: It's scrapy 1.4+?